# Subversion: merge moved file

Tags: svn, merge, subclipse, file-move

I've moved (renamed) a file in a local SVN directory:

```
svn move src_file_path dst_file_path
```

When I've tried to `svn up`, I got:

```
D     C src_file_path
      >   local delete, incoming edit upon update
```

This means someone else edited the file that I moved.

How do I merge the changes made by the other contributor into the new location?

PS - This is the same branch, unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064321/subversion-cant-merge-after-a-move).

Answer (score 1):

You got a tree conflict.  Take the Show > Tree Conflicts option and then take the Resolve option on the tree conflict.  This will launch a wizard that gives you options based on the conflict.  In this case, one of those will help you merge changes into the new location.

Answer (score -1):

Merge file in WC with file in repo

Comment: @AdamMatan `svn help merge` is *old fashion* now?!

Comment: "RTFM" isn't the spirit of SO. Why not supply a clear, working solution that ranr can refer to?