# SVN Merging from Trunk to a Branch containing rearranged files

Tags: svn

SVN 1.6.12 question - Suppose I create a branch off of trunk.

Then in that branch I rearrange many of the files into different directories under that branch (using the repository's server view in Eclipse).

Now suppose some people are modifying the trunk files whereas I am working on the branch, and I want to merge their changes into my branch.

If I merge from the project root in trunk back into my branch, would that work, even on the moved files?

Of course in CVS that would never have worked but since svn allows you to move files around on the server, I presume it is smart enough to know how to merge files that have changed directories.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVN has support for moving files, so if you move them in your trunk with

```
svn move
```

then this is going to be ok. Afterwards you should be able to svn merge normally.
However if there are other branches currently of your trunk , you must take some care:
[check this stackoverflow merge move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064321/subversion-cant-merge-after-a-move)
cheers!.