# Svn can't merge a directory move operation from trunk to branch

Tags: svn, merge

I'm using `svn` 1.6.11.

My project has one branch and I am refactoring to make the directory structure compatible with maven. (I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064321/subversion-cant-merge-after-a-move) already, but I think my situation is slightly different).

Everything was going perfectly as I was moving one dir at a time, committing to trunk, merging to branch and then committing to the branch in a cycle but the last directory I moved, svn won't merge the delete part of the move.

Only the copy part was merged.

I committed the merge to branch before I noticed and it looks like I've locked in the problem.

If I try to revert the commit, I get a conflict on the deleted directory.

What can I do to clean this up?

EDIT: I just worked out more. I made two further attempts at merging into the branch and I committed the attempts but the merges didn't delete the directory, they merged changes in the directory which had been made prior to the move action.

So svn merge thinks that trunk still has this directory, but it doesn't, the delete change was committed and even other earlier operations in that deleted directory are still visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what happened, I think.

On linux, some svn commands were getting blocked by the firewall and I'd missed the error.

I reverted revision by revision back to the point where it went wrong, and then started merging again. Then I hit this error:

```
Adding         Release-1.0.0/WebContent
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn:  Server sent unexpected return value (501 Method Not Implemented) 
        in response to COPY request for blah/blah/blah
```

So I figure on Friday I was just having a really bad day and had somehow manually intervened to get around that (and then worse, forgot that I'd done so).

Fortunately, svn in Eclipse doesn't have that problem - whether it's because my workstation is on the right side of the firewall or if it's because svn in Eclipse uses a different protocol, I'm not sure.

So I have successfully merged everything across to the branch now.